# R postgres connection error using dbxConnect

Tags: r, postgresql

I've got a postgres database hosted on Digital Ocean. On a server, I use the below R code without error and am able to connect. However, on my local machine (Mac, M1, 11.2.3) I get an error. Any ideas?

```
library(DBI)
library(RPostgres)
library(dbplyr)
library(dbx)


con <- dbxConnect(adapter = "postgres",
                  host = "db-postgresql-XXX.ondigitalocean.com",
                  port = 11111,
                  dbname = "XXXX",
                  user = "XXXX",
                  password = "XXXXX")
```

The error I get is:

> Error: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "XXX", user "XXXX", database "XXXX", SSL off

p.s. I've replaced sensitive stuff in the above with XXX etc.

Answer (score 0):

That is often a sign that you do are being barred from access by Postgres configurations.

You need to add your IP address to the  `pg_hba.conf` file (or your administrator does) and label it as trusted. Once this is done, you will likely not have that problem.

It is a security feature.

Comment: Any idea how to access that file on a managed Digital Ocean install? Also, it doesn't make sense that this is the problem because nothing should have changed on the DB install.

Comment: I have never worked in digital ocean, so I do not know.

Comment: @sconfluentus, the IP is quite often the problem, but as far as I can see, the problem here is indicated with the last part of the error message: "SSL off"., The new version tries to connect without SSL which in this case is not allowed. (In fact, the problem might have been any of the other parts, IP, user name or data base, all of them can be set in pg_hba.conf, but the only one that should change in this case is the SSL-status.

Comment: That makes sense. thanks for the insight @MortenSickel

Answer (score 0):

The is a problem with the newest version of the RPostgres library. Downgrading worked for me:

```
install.packages("RPostgres", repos = "https://r-dbi.r-universe.dev")
```

More info here:

https://github.com/r-dbi/RPostgres/issues/291